# Jquery - Verificar quando uma classe é removida pela ferramenta de desenvolvedor

Tags: jquery

Como verifico quando uma classe é removida pela ferramenta de desenvolvedor com jquery?

Comment: Como assim? queres ir ver na consola se um elemento tem uma dada classe? Se quiseres ver na consola podes fazer `document.querySelector('#meuElemento').classList` e isso dá-te uma array. Era isso que procuras?

Comment: Então no meu caso eu tinha uma tela de login e quando o usuário informasse a senha apareceria uma modal para ele alterar a senha se não tivesse de acordo com a regra, mas se o usuário tivesse conhecimento de programação conseguiria fazer o modal desaparecer e acessar o sistema normalmente. Resolvi esse problema com back-end .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não aconselho, mas segue o código

```
$(function(){
    var repetirEmMiliSegundos = 10000;//10 segundos
    setInterval(function() {
            if($('.nomeDaClasse').length > 0){
            //Ainda existe 
            }
        }, repetirEmMiliSegundos);
    });
```

É só rodar um js em "background".

http://paulohdsousa.blogspot.com.br/2015/08/dica-como-rodar-javascript-em-background.html

Comment: +1 só não entendi o por que do setInterval() mas o $(<selector>).length eu faço uso igual explicou

Comment: @SneepS NinjA Repete um código em X tempos que você especificar  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: rsrsr sim, quis dizer nesse caso. Mas como o AP não detalhou muito nem colocou um pedaço de código fica em aberto esse tipo de interpretação, eu não tinha entendido a necessidade de uma repetição para resolver esse caso, só isso :D